# Trying to get custom product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, magento-1, session

I am using Magento 1.9.2.

I have custom product attribute for every product in my store. The attribute code is `product_link`.

I have this code to get all products in the current cart session:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
$app = Mage::app('default'); 
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $ProductLink = $item->getProduct()->getProductLink();
    $ProductName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    echo "ProductLink: $ProductLink - ProductName: $ProductName<br>";
}
```

I have no problem to get the name of the product which is a default attribute.
However i can not get the link value in `product_link` attribute which all products have.

Where is my mistake how may i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that:

```
$ProductLink = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getProductLink();
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading the entire product just to get one attribute is very bad in terms of performance here's what you should do:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
     ->addAttributeToSelect('product_link')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id',  $item->getProduct()->getId())
     ->setPageSize(1);

$productLink = $collection->getFirstItem()->getProductLink();
```